# How to generate an Espresso test report from the command line

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line-arguments, android-espresso, android-testing

When running Espresso tests from the command line, I need to also generate a test report.

I run my tests from the command line in the standard way:

`adb -d shell am instrument -w -e log true -e package com.mycompany.myproject/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner > log.txt`

But I need to generate the test report html file created from within the Android Studio IDE using the **Export Test Results...** icon button on the **Run** tool window. Is there a flag that does this?

So far I can only run the tests from the command line without generating a test report output file, as I found no flags to generate the report.

I am trying to do this with the tools Google makes available to Android developers. It would think the capability must already exist, without having to write a custom test runner, etc. Also, the custom test runner suggested does not create the html output, neither has it been maintained for the last several years.